# Why i cant use "i" value of for loops in ggplot graphs?

Tags: r, loops, ggplot2, bar-chart

i have a boolean data set [data set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUZHe.png)

im trying to get bar graph for every columns.I can do that manually
for example:
`ggplot(data=data14)+
  geom_bar(aes(x=data14$X35,fill=X35))`

thats working but if i try with for loop it cant works

```
for (i in colnames(data14)){  plot[i] <-ggplot(data=data14)+geom_bar(aes(x=i,fill=i)) }
```

I want to send all plot to plot1,plot2... values.

and i tried to do that manually for test. For example:

```
    i="X1"
ggplot(data=data14)+
geom_bar(aes(x=i,fill=i))
```

For this codes R giving me this graph:[graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PktHS.png)

How can i set "i" value of my for loops in ggplot graphs?

Comment: You should initialise plot(name it something else btw). Maybe use a list?

Comment: Please provide data with `dput(head(df,n))` not images.

Comment: Putting the data in long format and changing the code to `ggplot(data = data14 %>% filter(Key == i), aes(x = Key, y = value))` will also work. But @NelsonGon answer without loop is way better.

Comment: Or you could use `aes_string`.

Answer (score 2):

A loop free solution that uses iris for reproducibility:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
my_plots<-Map(function(x) ggplot(data=iris, aes(x=!!sym(x),
                                 fill=!!sym(x)))+
        geom_bar(), colnames(iris))
```

Result(fifth plot):

`my_plots[[5]]`

[image]

**NOTES**

1. Using `fill` requires `factor`s as far as I know which is why only the fifth plot in this solution actually has coloured bars.

Answer (score 1):

The problem why your loop doesn't work with `aes()` is that you have to use `aes_string` in this case, like so:

```
attach(iris)

for(i in names(iris)[-5]){
  print(ggplot(data=iris) + geom_bar(aes_string(x=i,fill=i)))
}
```

However, note, that this solution is not optimal and you should proceed as NelsonGon suggested. Can you make an example how your desired plot should look like?